# About MongoDB repair's working (option, log, progress or so)

Tags: mongodb, repair

MongoDB was accidentally broken, and now in 'repair'. (wiredTiger, old version 3.6)

1. In my case, repair work is more needed really for some instances, so if there is available option, I consider to use it and firstly to skip less necessary but more indexes, probably erroneous ones.
   (But the job is likely to proceed all the data through instances, especially for 'wiredTiger' which is named for a sort of 'interleaved' status, then no way to prioritize, though.)
2. Second, repair is likely to work longer for those with more indexes, and longer for more data (even with less indexes),
   whatever, progress log messages are in standard-out, BTW time expectation seems difficult (just keeping going even no log for four hours). Instances are different in size of less than 100GB or more than 1TB.
3. Logs being shown on screen would be saved as any file?
4. If there are some problems, assuming a certain instance has ones (e.g, complexity, poor structure, etc and as a result caused crash), the repair could give some of left crashed and others rescued?
5. And, practically there is no more possible method to recover instances if repair finally fails?

Comment: 1) From log data, a possibility of crash is about specific index file. Then is it available to try to start daemon without index files? If it needs them when start, system would recreate index files again? Otherwise crashed again due to lack of them?

Comment: Now I'm trying to use "wt" utility for wiredTiger files.
http://source.wiredtiger.com/3.2.1/command_line.html
Intuitively it should be great of use.
BTW, while googling about it, it looks not quite much of use and not easy to use according to usage guide page.